# É possível exportar o código fonte de um projeto Android Studio? Como?

Tags: android, android-studio

Desenvolvi um aplicativo no Android Studio que já está disponível na Google Play.

Como foi um projeto que usei como tema do meu TCC, a universidade precisa do código fonte em PDF. Como eu extraio o código em um arquivo só?

Meu projeto tem várias classes e realizar toda a junção de código manualmente é praticamente inviável. Pesquisei e parece que dá pra exportar caso o aplicativo já esteja na Google Play e eu instale a versão APK no meu dispositivo, mas não tenho  celular Android.

É possível fazer isso pelo computador, com o meu código sem ser compilado? Como?

Comment: é necessário até mesmo os códigos das activitys ?

Comment: Se você tem o projeto, basta copiar os códigos jogar no world e mandar salvar como PDF. Não entendi bem o que você perguntou. ... Se o que você deseja é documentar o código, então vou logo lhe dizendo, não existe caminho mágico para documentar as coisas, isso é um processo manual e feito por pessoas e equipes.

Answer (score 1):

Rafaela o Android Studio, não tem uma função de "exportar" todo o código, o que eu te recomendaria é colocar seu projeto inteiro no GitHub ou algo semelhante e deixar publico como eu fiz no meu tema de TCC. Assim seus professores conseguirão baixar e analisar o seu projeto ou apenas olhar seus códigos no próprio site do GitHub.

Outra coisa que você poderia fazer que não acho que seja viável, seria copiar seus códigos e separar em apenas uma pasta.

Comment: Então, ele já tá no github, mas é que eu tenho que registrar a patente no setor de tecnologia e eles pedem o código-fonte em pdf.

Comment: Então @RafaelaLopes, a forma de você fazer isso é copiando os códigos mesmo hehe

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso irá resolver:

Instale o virtualBox Oracle: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Baixe alguma ISO do android: http://www.android-x86.org/download

Instale essa iso no virtualBox: https://www.segredosgeek.com/2013/06/tutorial-como-instalar-o-android-no-virtual-box.html

Autorize o root: Aqui você vai ter que pesquisar pois vai dependender da versão que escolher, apesar de ser quase igual em todas.

Depois do root, você vai baixar o titaniumBackup, depois de instalar clique em 'Backup/Restauração' e escolha o seu aplicativo, ai conecte seu seu celular no PC, e vai ter a pasta do backup do titanium, copie ela pro seu PC e vais ver que dentro dela vai estar seu APK.

Mude o formato para ZIP ou RAR e descompacte, depois use o Dex2Jar para fazer a reversão.

Converta novamente esse .JAR gerado para .ZIP, agora vais precisar converter os .class em .JAVA, pra isso use a ferramenta Java Decompiler -> JD-GUI.

Agora vais ter o código fonte completo, mas pra agrupar tudo, não sei dizer se você consegue com Android Studio, mas no netbeans você pode instalar ele com a versão JAVA, e tentar combinar os .JAR, mas também não tenho certeza se será completo, não trabalho com dev android, o máximo que vou saber ajudar é isso.

Comment: E o pior é que não faz muito sentido agrupar todo o código hehe, tal do professor te contar viu... kk

Comment: Realmente é uma parada diferenciada, mas talvez seja pra analisar consistencia do número de linhas, ou blocos, mas é estranho kk

Comment: Eu preciso agrupar o código todo p/ solicitação de patente, rs

Comment: @RafaelaLopes se for solicitação de patente e vc tem acesso ao source basta copiar um a um e colocar no World e depois mandar imprimir pra PDF.

Comment: Fiz isso, Guilherme! Obrigada! :D

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer o seu código fonte, se foi isso mesmo, veja esse tutorial, já consegui fazer por ele.

http://www.dicastech.net/tutorial-extrair-codigo-fonte-android/